# What are the Integer values of Boolean False and True in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I'm working with a bit of old VB6 code that goes thus...

```
Dim STATUS As Integer

STATUS = -1

If (Not STATUS) Then
' do something
Else
' do something else
End If
```

so I was, naturally, wondering which branch of this code is executed. So does anyone know what the numeric values of True and False are in VB6?

Comment: The real question is why does the original code not use a `Boolean` in the first place?

Comment: @Cody Gray, That is indeed a good question.

Comment: @Cody, @Brian If the code is really old, it may predate the introduction of `Boolean` into the language. AFAICR `Boolean` was introduced in VB4.

Comment: @MarkJ What you say is true, but there were constants named `True` and `False` available since VB1, so it's just bad code IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

True is stored as -1 and false as 0. Any non-zero value is considered as true.

To see why it is so please check - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=405047

Comment: "Any non-zero value is considered as true" -- why then does `? (55 = True)` return `False`?

Comment: Good question and I would like to know the answer - anyone?

Comment: I am not 100% sure .. but In this case 55 is not converted to bool value and maybe it compares 55 and -1 to return false. If you create a bool variable and assign 55 to it and then compare, the result will be true.

Comment: Any non-zero value is true **when casted to boolean** (assignment, CBool)

Comment: @onedaywhen  `True` is stored as `-1` therefore `55 = True` is equivalent to `55 = -1` which is `False`

Comment: @Roland: I think my original comment was mean to convey, just because VB6 allows one to write loosely-typed code, doesn't mean it is a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 11):

**In VB 6, `True` has a numeric value of -1. `False` has a numeric value of 0.**

The reason for this is because the `Boolean` data type is stored as a 16-bit signed integer. Therefore,
-1 evaluates to 16 1s in binary (1111111111111111). `False` is 16 0s (0000000000000000). This produces the relationship that has held throughout the evolution of BASIC: `True = Not False`.

Comment: +1. It's also worth knowing that the VB6 `Not` is always the arithmetic operator, there's no separate logical `Not` operator. Thanks to type coercion, you can use `Not` with Booleans as if it were a logical operator.

Comment: The reasons are explained in more detail in [this nice article from 2001](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/truth.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but just poking about, I typed this into the immediate window, with these results:

```
For x = -5 To 5 : ? x, CBool(x), ( x = True ), ( x = False ) : Next x
-5            True          False         False
-4            True          False         False
-3            True          False         False
-2            True          False         False
-1            True          True          False
 0            False         False         True
 1            True          False         False
 2            True          False         False
 3            True          False         False
 4            True          False         False
 5            True          False         False
```

(I tested more values, but only -1 and 0 had anything "interesting" going on.  The rest were all True/False/False.)  So, empirically, I'd say that the comparison is being done arithmetically unless you cast with CBool.  Why?  I can't really say...

Comment: thank you for that. I didn't know you could do that sort of thing in the immediate window. Your results confirm what the other two posters have said.

Comment: The inability to use the immediate window the same way as VB6 still irritates me almost daily in VB.NET.