# Linq order by isn't ordering anything

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

```
// Query all records
var q =
dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(question => question.userID == UserID).Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse == true || question.awaitingSupportResponse == true).
OrderBy(s => s.awaitingUserResponse).ThenBy(s => s.dateSubmitted).
GroupJoin(
    dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
    question => question.ID,
    replies => replies.ticketID,
    (question, replies) => new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count() }
);
```

No matter where I put the order by query, it seems to just be ordering them randomly.

### Edit: same results with order at end:

```
// Query all records
var q =
dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(question => question.userID == UserID).Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse == true || question.awaitingSupportResponse == true).
GroupJoin(
    dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
    question => question.ID,
    replies => replies.ticketID,
    (question, replies) => new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count() }
).OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse).ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

### Edit: Generated SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t2].[ID], [t2].[catID], [t2].[subject], [t2].[question], [t2].[userID], [t2].[dateSubmitted], [t2].[isUrgent], [t2].[emailMe], [t2].[awaitingSupportResponse], [t2].[awaitingUserResponse], [t2].[lastReply], [t2].[stopWatchTotalMins], [t2].[isStopWatchOn], [t2].[stopWatchStart], [t2].[priorityLevel], [t2].[value] AS [RepliesCount]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[catID], [t0].[subject], [t0].[question], [t0].[userID], [t0].[dateSubmitted], [t0].[isUrgent], [t0].[emailMe], [t0].[awaitingSupportResponse], [t0].[awaitingUserResponse], [t0].[lastReply], [t0].[stopWatchTotalMins], [t0].[isStopWatchOn], [t0].[stopWatchStart], [t0].[priorityLevel], (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [dbo].[tblHelpCentreReplies] AS [t1]
        WHERE ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[ticketID]
        ) AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[tblHelpCentreQuestions] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE (([t2].[awaitingUserResponse] = @p0) OR ([t2].[awaitingSupportResponse] = @p1)) AND ([t2].[userID] = @p2)
ORDER BY [t2].[awaitingUserResponse], [t2].[dateSubmitted]', N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int', @p0 = 1, @p1 = 1, @p2 = 81
```

I've run the code through the database and it returns the results correctly, so it must be something else which is strange because the code is so simple, never mind though, thanks all for your help, I've learnt a lot of new things with this problem!

Comment: what are you trying to order? You are doing a join after the ordering, so the order is destroyed basically.

Comment: What about after `GroupJoin`?

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408177/linq-order-by-boolean

Comment: Can you have a lot at the SQL generated in both cases?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to answer it. Based alone on the code you posted, the results should be ordered. Maybe you are doing something wrong when iterating over these results (since you’ve only shown us the query, not how you use it).

Comment: @Timwi it's really simple code, it just dumps the results in an array afterwards then binds it to a repeater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this LINQ to SQL? I suspect the problem is that you're ordering *before* the grouping. You could try this:

```
var q = dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
          .Where(question => question.userID == UserID)
          .Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse
                          || question.awaitingSupportResponse)
          .GroupJoin(dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
                     question => question.ID,
                     replies => replies.ticketID,
                     (question, replies) => new { Question = question,
                                                RepliesCount = replies.Count() })
          .OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse)
          .ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

EDIT: Okay, if this isn't working then perhaps it's a limitation of SQL grouping... although that seems pretty odd.

You could always force the ordering to be performed at the client side instead though:

```
var q = dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
          .Where(question => question.userID == UserID)
          .Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse
                          || question.awaitingSupportResponse)
          .GroupJoin(dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
                     question => question.ID,
                     replies => replies.ticketID,
                     (question, replies) => new { Question = question,
                                                RepliesCount = replies.Count() })
          // Force the rest of the query to execute in .NET code (Enumerable.XXX)
          .AsEnumerable()
          .OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse)
          .ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, same result though :S

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq/204777#204777) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx), `GroupJoin` preserves ordering

Comment: @BlueRaja: That's LINQ to Objects, which is an entirely different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Tom: I've edited with a suggestion. I'm still surprised it's not working though... what does the SQL look like?

Comment: @BlueRaja: while [Enumerable.GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) does make guarantees about order, no such guarantees are documented for [Queryable.GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805.aspx).

Comment: @BlueRaja - I'm guessing it's L2S based on the presence of a DataContext.  I don't think that would hold true in Linq to SQL where the OrderBy has to be translated and executed server side.  SQL Server is inherently flippant about order in general unless that's the last operation executed.

Comment: Also, X2 on the curiosity regarding the actual TSQL being generated here.  L2S is making a mistake in translating the query if moving the order operations to the end of the expression chain failed.

Comment: Back home from work at the moment, I'll try and get the SQL tommorow to see what's going on

Comment: @Pete I've included the SQL that was generated by viewing SQL server profiler

Comment: I'm a moron, sorry for wasting all your time but I've learnt a lot from all this anyway

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried moving the OrderBy to the very last operation, just before the ;?  Like SQL, I wouldn't expect to receive an ordered set if I performed ANY operations on it after I did the ordering...  I'd be curious to see what the actual SQL generated is when presented in that order.

Edit for code exploring using ToList() to force execution, then do the ordering clientside:

```
var q = dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
    .Where(question => question.userID == UserID)
    .Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse == true || question.awaitingSupportResponse == true)
    .GroupJoin(
        dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
        question => question.ID,
        replies => replies.ticketID,
        (question, replies) => new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count() }
    )
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, same result though :S

Comment: Are you going to deal with the results right away?  How big of a data set is it?  You could call .ToList() to force the query to physically execute and get your in-memory set, then do your ordering "after the fact" as it were.

Answer (score 3):

The GroupJoin is most likely overriding the order. It's likely implemented as a subquery. If you run either LINQ to SQL Profiler or SQL profiler to see the underlying query, it would be able to shed light on this. Have you tried doing OrderBy as the last operation in the method chain?

Comment: Thanks for answering, same result though :S

Comment: What if you do `GroupJoin(...).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` so that the ordering is done in .NET as opposed to the database? This changes `q` from `IQueryable<anon>` to `IEnumerable<anon>`, but that might ok for the remaining code. Also, sometimes sorting is faster in .NET than SQL.

Comment: Very slight derail to @Jim and @Jon:  I see you both went with AsEnumerable() where I reflexively went to ToList().  Are there any negative implications for going the list route that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Jon: I didn't see that. Great Minds Think Alike.

Comment: @Pete: ToList() forces LINQ to create a List<T> which then gets immediated GC'd, whereas AsEnumerable() could potentially be more effecient, although I doubt it would be significant.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to order your grouped questions, you need to do that after you create the GroupJoin:

```
var q =
    dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(question => question.userID == UserID).Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse == true || question.awaitingSupportResponse == true).
    GroupJoin(
        dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
        question => question.ID,
        replies => replies.ticketID,
        (question, replies) => new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count() }
    ).
    AsEnumerable().
    OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse).
    ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

`GroupJoin` will effectively remove your ordering, since it's taking your ordered collection and grouping it by question.  `GroupJoin` does not preserve the initial ordering of the keys.

Edit: You can eliminate this issue by forcing the ordering to occur in LINQ to Objects, by converting to an enumerable after the GroupJoin.

Comment: Thanks for answering, same result though :S

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to test your code because I don’t have all your declarations, but I suspect that the reason you are getting seemingly random behaviour is because the `GroupJoin` makes no guarantees of keeping the order intact.

Therefore, you will have to do the ordering *after* the grouping.

For example:

```
var q = dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions
    .Where(question => question.userID == UserID)
    .Where(question => question.awaitingUserResponse == true || question.awaitingSupportResponse == true)
    .GroupJoin(
        dc.tblHelpCentreReplies,
        question => question.ID,
        replies => replies.ticketID,
        (question, replies) => new { Question = question, RepliesCount = replies.Count() }
    )
    .OrderBy(s => s.Question.awaitingUserResponse)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Question.dateSubmitted);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, same result though :S

Answer (score 2):

try adding ToArray() after your LINQ query. I do know that LINQ follows lazy evaluation rule, and ToArray() forces evaluation to be eager.