# Fetch and sort data from DB in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

Suppose I have some data like:

[image]

I want to fetch data in an order like, first give me all with IsActive == true and sort it in an alphabetical order by account name and then the false one sorted by account name.

How can I do it by _context.table.OrderBy() or some other method?

Comment: `OrderBy` `ThenBy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# List<> Sort by x then y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408177/linq-order-by-boolean) along with your comment @viveknuna helped me, how can I close the question?

Comment: @Mansi I am putting my anser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `OrderBy` on `IsActive` and then `ThenBy` on `AccountName`to sort the records.