# ordery_by is not working for boolean field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am running the query, but the ordery_by is not working for boolean field value. Any help, would be much appreciated. thank you.

models.py :

```
class ShopOffer(models.Model):
    offer_title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(ShopOwnerShopDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py :

```
queryset = ShopOffer.objects.filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by('-is_active')
```

Comment: Looks good, do you get any errors or messages?

Comment: Please define "not working" - how order_by is not working for you? Do you get wrong order?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev , I'm not getting any error. but i'm getting active and non active data even my query is for only non active data.

Comment: `order_by` is about sorting - so you will get false values first, then (after all records where is_active=False), you will get all records where is_active=True

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev  yes, that's what i'm expecting also...but i'm getting "True", and "False"  data instead of  only "False" data.

Comment: maybe you forgot to add the ".all()" part in your query, can you try: ShopOffer.objects.all().filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by('-is_active')

Comment: You query all the records filtered by specific user. And you also have `order_by`, which just change the sorting order. So it's expected that your query can return records where is_active is either True/False.

Comment: If you want to filter by both USER and IS_ACTIVE, you should make it as follows: `.filter(added_by__user_id=user, is_active=False)`.

Comment: @barbaart i tried it first. but it's also not working.

Comment: can you post your errors/messages ?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I want only sorting the `shopoffer` data.

Comment: @barbaart  i can share you my anydesk id. to see my live code.

Comment: You're working with ShopOffer data. You filter it. And then you sort filtered data with `order_by`. Sorting order - false first, true second.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev  yes i'm expecting this result first false then true. but i'm not getting the result as expected.

Comment: What do you see then?

Comment: I'm seeing reverse of this. means first `True` then `False` @DmitryBelaventsev

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Let's check what SQL do you have first. `print(ShopOffer.objects.filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by('-is_active').query)`

Comment: for "True" value is "1", for False value is "0"  @DmitryBelaventsev

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev  it's printing :   ORDER BY `shop_owner_shopoffer`.`is_active` DESC .

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: And can you show DDL of table for ShopOffer model?

Comment: Most likely in your database `is_active` is kind of integer field. So you get records where `is_active=1` (True) first and then `is_active=0` (False).

Comment: I have posted the answer with more details

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev here is the screenshot of the RDBMS of your request -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx1g4.png

Comment: So yea, it's MySQl and 99% it's TINYINT. So please look at my answer to get full understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Could you click on "Structure" button for "shop_owner_shopoffer" table and tell me exact type used for `is_active` field.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev yeah it's in `tinyint` field. I got understood why "is_active" menas "False" from your answer. thank you. really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely in your database that boolean field is stored as TINYINT (or other integer type). That means number `0` will represent False and number `1` will represent True. So when you make ORM call like this:

```py
ShopOffer.objects.filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by('-is_active')
```

Your SQL query contains this part:

```sql
ORDER BY shop_owner_shopoffer.is_active DESC
```

What does that mean. That means descending order for integer field. So greater numbers will come first, smaller numbers will come second. So `1` values (True) will come first, `0` values will come second. So `True` will come first, `False` will come second.

So if you want False values come first, your query should be like:

```py
ShopOffer.objects.filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by('is_active')
```

But once again, it all depends on RDBMS you use. I suggest to check DDL code of the table for `ShopOffer` table - to see the type of `is_active` field.

**UPDATE1**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx1g4.png

It's MySQL

**UPDATE2**

OP confirmed that it's TINYINT field

Answer (score 1):

Change it as below to get the default ordering false(0) to true(1)

```
queryset = ShopOffer.objects.filter(added_by__user_id=user).order_by(‘is_active’)
```

Comment: why shouldn't i use order_by for that? Any specific reason? actually my needed is for to sort this data by is active or not.

Comment: sort of filter?

Comment: filter changes number of records you get; ordering (sorting) is for just sorting of filtered set of records

Comment: Actually It's getting the  reverse of the data, means first "True" then "False".

Comment: Using orderby you get all the queries and then all the data with true are put on the top and false at the bottom  or reverse based on whether you use’-‘ or not

Comment: You’re getting reverse because you have used ‘-is_active’ instead of just ‘is_active’, the “-“ this changes the order to descending order

Comment: Actually i need to sort the whole queryset as ordey_by from non-active to active. @prathapsagar

Comment: Yes remove the “-“ infront of your is_active in the query

Comment: @prathapsagar '-is_active' means order_by from `False` to `True`. but i'm getting the result from `True` to `False`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408177/linq-order-by-boolean  As you can see here the default behaviour of order_by is false to true, you’re reversing it using the “-“ in front of your is_active so remove it, this is default ascending behaviour 0 (false) to 1(true), but adding a “-“ in front of your is_active changes it to descending order, you can read that in the document – https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/