Sorting by Int with Out-Of-Order Preference
Say I have a list of objects, which have a name and a score. Instead of just sorting by score, I actually have a preference for a particular object that should always be on top, and all remaining objects should be sorted by score. In my example below, there is only one such preferred object, but in reality there could be n objects that are preferred based on some field.
To start with, I'll make a list:
Tuple<String, int> apple = new("Apple", 1);
Tuple<String, int> banana = new("Banana", 2);
Tuple<String, int> coconut = new("Coconut", 3);
IEnumerable<Tuple<String, int>> allFruits = [banana, apple, coconut];

This so far is in the order "banana, apple, coconut".
I can then sort it by the score:
IEnumerable<Tuple<String, int>> sortedByInt = allFruits.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2);

This yields the order "coconut, banana, apple" which is expected given that's the order of the integer fields.
However, let's say that I have a preference for Apple and want that to be on top, but then the remaining two items can be sorted by score.
IEnumerable<Tuple<String, int>> sortedWithPreference = allFruits.OrderBy(x => x.Item1.Equals("Apple")).ThenByDescending(x => x.Item2);

This OrderBy and ThenBy doesn't actually work the way I thought it would. I assumed that the result would be "apple, coconut, banana", or in other words, my preferred item followed by the remaining items sorted by score. Instead, it returns them in the same order as the example above, "coconut, banana, apple", effectively ignoring the "OrderBy" clause.
Can anyone help to identify my mistake?
As I mentioned in the beginning, further complicating this would be a situation where there is more than one preferred item, such as this list:

Apple, 1
Apple, 2
Banana, 3
Coconut, 4

Which I would want to be in the order of:

Apple, 2
Apple, 1
Coconut, 4
Banana, 3

Or in other words: the preferred items are at the top, sorted by score, followed by all other items, sorted by score. Can anyone help to make this work for n preferred items?
I can do this without the fancy LINQ OrderBy's by pulling out my preferred items into their own list and sorting them separately, but if there's an easier way to do this with LINQ, that would be great!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408177/linq-order-by-boolean

Try .OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1.Equals("Apple")), so that the true value sorts first.
