# C++ memcmp fails with unsigned char array?

Tags: c++, memcmp

I got a probably small problem using memcmp. I have two arrays (length = 3 byte) with exactly the same data.

If I try to compare them with memcmp, it fails?!

```
if (memcmp(ucbuffer, ucnewbuffer, buffer.sDeviceData.sLenght)) {
    cout << "val written, val ok!\n";
};
```

ucbuffer, ucnewbuffer are both unsigned char * and were allocated using

```
calloc(buffer.sDeviceData.sLenght, sizeof(unsigned char);
```

If i compare both arrays by hand, both it will result in being exactly the same.

Do you have any Idea?

Have a nice evening.

Comment: Post all the code, not just snippets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That function returns *zero* (i.e., not true) when the buffers compare equal.

Comment: I thought true = 0, false -1 so checking for 0 means true?! Hm... if you're right, than the rest of my code doesn't work either...

Comment: checking for 0 in this case means that the comparison is equal, 0 traditionally is false though

Comment: *Any* C or C++ reference should tell you that false is zero and true is one (plus all other non-zero values). It's common for functions to return zero on *success*, and in that case, a non-zero result will sometimes indicate the error code. Maybe you were thinking of that and confused it with this situation. But `memcpy` has no failure result. Even if the buffers aren't equal, the function still *succeeds* in telling you the result. If it helps you remember, `memcpy` returns the same way as `strcpy`; the sign of the result tells you which argument should be sorted ahead of the other.

Comment: Well yea, I come frome the Visual Basic corner were -1 is false, and >= 0 is true. That might have made me thinking, 0 is true.

Comment: Even in Visual Basic, False is zero. It's *True* that's -1. [cite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4275800/33732)

Comment: Oh well, damn, it's quite a long time ago I got in touch with programming. Astonishing how you mix up some things after a couple of years :) Thank you all guys. You really helped me.