# Entity Framework 6 - Mapping negative 1 to C# true

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, boolean

I have an existing system which for some reason, which I can't fathom for the life of me, has negative 1 (-1) as the representation of true in the database (Oracle 12.C)

I would really like to be able to map this in EF 6 to a boolean value without the pain of having a wrapping property.

Anyone know of a way to support this scenario?  The trouble I am seeing is that linq queries like Where(v => !v.IsDeleted) will generate SQL which is positive 1 orientated i.e. WHERE (item.IS_DELETED <> 1))

If I could get the SQL generated to be more interested in the relationship to false (Zero value) then I can keep my C# code agnostic

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Binary trivia for the day - in C `TRUE` is often defined as 0xFFFFFFFF, which when cast to an integer becomes -1.

Comment: Also, true is -1 in Visual Basic prior to VB.NET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275800/what-are-the-integer-values-of-boolean-false-and-true-in-vb6#4275828.

Comment: :) ok, so there are some non crazy exceptions.  I just need to convince EF to play along with the situation.  Exploring using an Enum type... but seeing CASTING going on in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on using an Enum to represent the boolean

```
public enum BooleanType
{
    False = 0,
    True = -1
}
```

As EF doesn't correctly support Enum Properties (It will CAST in ORACLE)
I then added a Linq Extension method to remove the unnessary casts.

```
public class RemoveCastVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal) {
            var leftUnary = node.Left as UnaryExpression;
            var rightUnary = node.Right as UnaryExpression;

            if (leftUnary == Null || rightUnary == Null)
                return base.VisitBinary(node);

            if (leftUnary.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
                return base.VisitBinary(node);

            if (rightUnary.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
                return base.VisitBinary(node);

            return Expression.Equal(leftUnary.Operand, rightUnary.Operand);
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
}


public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes ANY Casting from the Query Expression
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<T> RemoveCasts<T>(this IQueryable<T> q)
    {
        var visitor = new RemoveCastVisitor();
        Expression original = q.Expression;
        var expr = visitor.Visit(original);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expr);
    }
}
```

And here is my test showing it working

```
IQueryable<int> query = context.Set<UnitTest>().Where(v => v.IsDeleted == BooleanType.True).Select(v => v.Id);
query = query.RemoveCasts();
var sql = ((DbQuery<int>)query).ToString();

var expected =
    "SELECT \r\n" +
    "\"Extent1\".\"ID\" AS \"ID\"\r\n" +
    "FROM \"EZIAUS\".\"ZZ_UNIT_TEST\" \"Extent1\"\r\n" +
    "WHERE (-1 = \"Extent1\".\"IsDeleted\")";

Assert.AreEqual(expected, sql);
```

Comment: To be clear the IsDeleted property is of type BooleanType

Answer (score 1):

I will take adavantage of **TPH (Table Per Hierarchy)** ORM pattern with EF. With this pattern all your base class and derived classes witl share same table. Each row of the table will be differentiate by a discriminator.

First I will have this abstract class so let's name it `WeirdModel`:

```
public abstract class WeirdModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a two derived classes from `WeirdModel` let's name them: `TrueWeirdModel` and  `FalseWeirdModel`:

```
public class TrueWeirdModel : WeirdModel
{
}

public class FalseWeirdModel : WeirdModel
{
}
```

My context's definition will look like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WeirdModel> Weirds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FalseWeirdModel> FalseWeirdModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrueWeirdModel> TrueWeirdModels { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
        : base("MyContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WeirdModel>()
            .Map<TrueWeirdModel>(p => p.Requires("WeirdBoolean").HasValue(-1))
            .Map<FalseWeirdModel>(p => p.Requires("WeirdBoolean").HasValue(1));
    }
}
```

Here I say that WeirdBoolean column on DB will contain

- `-1` for `TrueWeirdModel`
- `1` for `FalseWeirdModel`

To use them:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var trueWeirdData = new TrueWeirdModel { SomeProperty = "true weird model" };
    var falseWeirdData = new FalseWeirdModel { SomeProperty = "false weird model" };

    context.Weirds.AddRange(new WeirdModel[] { trueWeirdData, falseWeirdData });

    context.SaveChanges();
}

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var allWeirdModels = context.Weirds.ToList();

    var allTrueWeirdData = context.TrueWeirdModels.ToList();

    var allFalseWeidData = context.FalseWeirdModels.ToList();
}
```

In your database we will have this:

[image]

With TPH ORM pattern you will never manipulate the weird column `WeirdBoolean` which is used as a discriminator.  BTW you still can create a property that map to it.

In your whole application you will never have to use this column as a filter in your Linq To Entities queries. The `where` filter for `WeirfBoolean` will be automatically added when using `TruesWeirdModels` or `FalseWeirdModels` `Dbset`. To get them all you just use the abstract class `WeirdModels` `DbSet`. Because `WeirdModel` is an abstract class you can't instantiate it, you must use `FalseWeirdModel`or `TrueWeirdModel` if you want to create a new row on your table.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I ended up working with Enums instead.  As boolean's are used in multiple places I'm not sure if your solution would have enough flexiblity