# Is it possible to set a property via the setter of a property used to convert a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We're using EFCore with an Azure SQL Database. One of the columns `Yodels` is a tinyint which can only be mapped to a byte in C# but we want to use it with a checkbox on a web form which requires a bool. To display it we're accessing it via an additional property `YodelsBool` which converts it to a bool.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte Yodels { get; set; }

    public bool YodelsBool
    {
        get {
            return Yodels > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The checkbox on the form: `<input asp-for="Person.YodelsBool" class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="Person.YodelsBool" />`

We'd like to be able to also set the value via this YodelsBool property. Is that possible? When we add a setter it fails `Invalid column name 'YodelsBool'` because it is trying to update the database for that specific property.

We've tried a setter:

```
    public bool YodelsBool
    {
        get {
            return Yodels > 0;
        }
        set {
                Yodels = Covert.ToByte(value);
        }
    }
```

How can we make this work without changing the database? We're using tinyint in case we want to expand beyond true/false sometime in the future.

Comment: Can't you [ignore](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/notmapped-attribute) the `YodelsBool` property in EF?

Comment: Yes that is the answer, as per @D Stanley. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'd be much happier with `Yodels = value ? 1 : 0;` than using `Covert.ToByte(value);`.  A year from now, a maintenance programmer will need to go look up what `Covert.ToByte(bool);` does.

Comment: I actually prefer the explicit conversion rather than having to remember that true=1 and false=0. That said, the getter assumes that false = 0, so maybe consistency is better...

Comment: @Flydog57 that's what documentation is for, right? It's commented in the code which (I hope) is more important than which of the two is used. That is less cluttered though.

Comment: Actually, a getter that looks like `Yodels != 0` is probably better anyway.  You never know, VB6 used `-1` as True: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275800/what-are-the-integer-values-of-boolean-false-and-true-in-vb6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[NotMapped]` to the property:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool YodelsBool
{
    get {
        return Yodels > 0;
    }
    set {
            Yodels = Covert.ToByte(value);
    }
}
```